# User create its content type

Tags: nodes, users

I created a content type called *successful story*; in this content type, there is a title field and a text field.

I have two types of users, Role1 and Role2; Role2 can only create or delete a *successful story*.

For example, The user called Michael is a Role2 user and can create its successful story

But how can I make this relation works between a content type and an user?

Comment: Hello! I think I did not understand your last phrasing "But how can I make this relation works between a content type and an user ?". Can you please rephrase it here in the comments?

Comment: I re-edit my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear but I think you want to know how to set the right access to the different Roles

1. Go to your_site/admin/people/permissions
2. Search from the successful store content type
3. For Role 2 check the "Create new content" and "Delete own content"
4. Click save at the end of page

Now users of Role 2 can create and delete their own content.

You can also create a link for Role 2 users to access their own content.

1. Go to your_site/admin/people/permissions
2. Search from the Access the content overview page
3. For Role 2 check the box for Role 2
4. Click save at the end of page
5. Create a menu item and add the link as admin/content

Answer (score 0):

Go to admin/people/permissions where you can set permissions for every content type - creating/deleting/modifiyng own/any content